# Allow user to change Default text of a label, so new text is viewed the next time the program is run. (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How do I save changes a user makes to a label's text property so that when the user closes the program and runs it again their changes are still in the label's text property?

User needs to change the text in a label and have those changes saved in such a way that when the program is run the next time the user's changes need to be in the label not the label's original content.  `StreamReader/ Writer` are not an option for this program.

I am doing this by changing the default text setting for the label:

```
    private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //   Properties.Settings.Default.listLabel = "Test";
         Properties.Settings.Default.listLabel = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

but `listLabel` is getting an error.

> Error: 'Project.Properties.Settings.' does not contain a definition
>   for 'listLabel' and no extension method 'listLabel' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Project.Properties.Settings.' could be found.

Comment: Have you created the setting?

Comment: I set the Text field in the properties window.  I thought that set the default for the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure in the Settings.settings file that you have an entry called "listLabel" that is a string. Its a pretty strait forward data grid that you just add your variable with the scope set to 'User'.

You also need to make sure that you save afterwords using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That plus, MSDN's documentation at link below gave me all I needed.  I am very great full.       http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddeaca86-a093-4997-82c9-01bc0c630138/propertiessettingsdefaultsave-does-not-save-a-userconfig-file?forum=csharpgeneral